# pdf417 barcode reader/decoder in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, barcode-scanner

I would like to read/decode pdf417 barcode from my web app targeted to run only on mobile browsers. I have seen many barcode reader javascript libs online but none of them supporting reading of pdf417 barcode(one of the most popular barcode type) off-course creation of pdf417 was supported by them.

What I am looking for is a javascript based library to read/decode pdf417 barcode, I know how to achieve this with phonegap or native. I am expecting purely js based solution

Comment: did u get any solution.

Comment: @madan V No luck yet.

Answer (score 3):

We created a library to do just that, https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/js-zxing-pdf417, unlike the Android-only solution above this is pure Javascript and will work in all browsers.

Comment: Hello, I tried to implement this on some other barcode images but it was returning an empty array. Can you please review/help?

Comment: Same here. @rmhrisk project always return an empty array. The best thing that I have achieved with zxing library is that it works sometimes randomly... 1 of 5 reads ok, 2 or 3 doesn't find anything and the others waits for the resolution of the promise that never comes.

Comment: You must have a large enough image that is sufficiently high quality for it to work.

Comment: I can confirm. Does not scan anything.

Answer (score -1):

If you're mainly interested in Android, take a look at this fork of the popular barcodescanner plugin, it supports PDF417: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/BarcodeScanner

Comment: Looking for a solution in pure javascript without dependency on native code.

Comment: @GaneshK did you have any luck in finding pure js solution?

Comment: Nope, I left this long back.